# How do I prevent React Native devtools from launching in the browser when I enable debugging?

Tags: react-native, flipper, fbflipper

I'm attempting to debug my React Native app with [Flipper](https://fbflipper.com/), and every time I open the developer menu and choose Debug, it launches a browser tab with the debugging UI. This doesn't happen when I have [React Native Debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger) running, but for some reason it does with Flipper.